# Incompatibility with Xcode 4.5?

Tags: c4

The [available C4 installer](http://www.c4ios.com/tutorials/getstarted.php) throws a generic "Installation Failed" error after attempting to install. Is it incompatible with 4.5, or is it simply the installer package that is incompatible?

Edit: It fails on "Validating Packages".

Answer (score 2):

It installs and works fine, just doesn't validate. Weird

Comment: There is a problem with the installer, but it's not a 
Somehow it fails, but still installs code and template files anyways.
Thanks for finding where it fails, I will be able to fix it now... I've been looking for where the installer fails for a while.